# iPhone - Is it possible to write an application over Bluetooth to connect with non-iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I developed a headset device that can connect to iPhone (HFP + A2DP + AVRCP). I want to write an application that will also send and receive data (a few bytes) to/from the headset over Bluetooth.
Actually I want to open a Bluetooth connection between iPhone and my device to transfer data.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible if you are a member of the "Made for iPhone" ([MFI](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)) program.
This mean your hardware will have to follow apple protocol.